# Kafka Consumer polling from incorrect offset?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a monitoring service for different Kafka brokers and I am trying to get the time lag (record.timestamp - currentTimestamp).

The issue that I'm seeing from my time lag for a majority of brokers is that the time lag reported is a couple of days instead of a couple of minutes/hours.

From my code, I am using `assign()` and `seek()` to grab the latest committed offset of a particular topic and partition and using that timestamp to calculate the time lag.

```java
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>();
long offset = 1234567;
consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(new TopicPartition("test-topic", 0)));
consumer.seek(new TopicPartition("test-topic", offset));
ConsumerRecords<String, String> recordMap = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
long timeDifference = -1;
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if(!recordMap.isEmpty()){
   timeDifference = currentTime - recordMap.first().timestamp();
}
```

I'm pretty sure the math should be legit, but not sure if there are some other conditions that have to do with properties of Kafka brokers that I'm not taking into account as to why all the timeDifference would return a couple of days.

Comment: Poll doesn't return a Hashmap... But producers can set whatever timestamp they want in each record, so while your logic could be correct, it assumes record timestamps will always be the time data was produced. Also, use seekToEnd to get latest committed offset

Comment: I made the changes for poll() to return ConsumerRecord. Does `seekToEnd()` vs `seek()` make a difference here? I have some logic that checks if the offset is last committed offset, if not use earliest offset `long offset = lastCommittedOffset == -1 ? earliestOffset : lastCommittedOffset`



As for the timestamps, I'm assuming that another team's produces these messages a couple of days back and send it to our consumers. Is there a way to check the timestamp in which the messages reaches our consumers?